# how to clear the docker nginx file cache

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx running in docker as a static server. When I update the server side folder `template.xlsx` file. the download still return the old file, I am sure I have replace the static `template.xlsx` file to a new one. how to make the nginx return the new nginx file? this is the static nginx config:

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.com/fullchain1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.com/privkey1.pem;

    server_name static.example.com;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';


        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

I tried to restart the docker container seems still did not return the new template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default nginx uses `off` by [expires](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) directive.
This means that nginx doesn't add or modify the “Expires” and “Cache-Control” response header fields.
For a static file this would mean that client (browser) in absence of both headers has a free choice how it would cache the resource (it is quasi an undefined behavior for you related to [HTTP spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) because it may store a successful response for example for current session or even longer for some fixed time, depending on its settings unless it's refreshing the request (F5/Ctrl+F5 from browser or `If-Modified-Since`, `If-None-Match`, `Cache-Control` or `Pragma` request headers from client).

Restart of nginx (or docker container) would not help here at all, since it is browser/client side that can use cached file. In browsers you could use DevTools (F12) -> Network to monitor what exactly happens if you start a download (and which headers your browser sends by request and receives with response from nginx).

You can:

- either disable cache for this file (location), using `expires -1;` or adding `Cache-Control: no-cache` header (just note that it is not advisable to completely disable cache for everything static, at least don't do that for resources that changes very rare, like pictures, styles and JS)
- or force browser/client to reload it using different URI like `template.xlsx?ver=2`, e. g. send a request with some incremental suffix like `?ver=...` here (or simple a timestamp);
- or force browser/client to reload it with F5/Ctrl+F5 in case of browser or `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Pragma: no-cache` headers from some HTTP client;